# I want to get the result which should be less time consuming

Tags: sql, postgresql, query-optimization

```
select count(*) 
from table 
where EXTRACT(MONTH FROM addondatetime) = EXTRACT(MONTH FROM current_date) 
  and EXTRACT(year FROM addondatetime) = EXTRACT(year FROM current_date)
```

this is my query. i want to extract month from table which is equal to current month but this query is taking almost 2 min

Comment: you should think about indexing your table maybe

Comment: Do you have an index on `addondatetime`?

Comment: Try finding the start date, End Date of the month and use addondatetime between startdate and enddate. Also use count(1) Instead of *

Comment: What is the best way to index date col? Plus i forgot to mention this is foreign server's wrapper

Comment: did you try this : select * from (select current_date) as drt where  to_char(current_date,'YYYY-MM')=to_char(current_date,'YYYY-MM') ., post the execution time?

Comment: taking same amount of time

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
select count(*) 
from table 
where date_trunc('month', addondatetime) = date_trunc('month', current_date);
```

Also create a function based index:

```
create index test_just_month on test (date_trunc('month', addondatetime));
```

Comment: same time. its the foreign wrapper tho